# How to make multiple audio in one page

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I want to make an interface that has multiple audio, so when user clicks on icon play, it will play the audio of that letter. Do i have to use loop or what? Please send helpp. I tried but it's not working. The codes is in mess T_T . Thank you in advance.

[This is the picture of interface example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qT56e.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Flutter package to easily do that: [just_audio](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio).

First define an `AudioPlayer` object, then set its asset file with something like:

```
player.setAsset('assets/$filename');
```

Then you can control it using:

```
player.play()
player.stop()
```

You should be able to follow the example project in the pub link.

Comment: Thank youuuu. This helps me understand more about audio. I will try this one